# ggplot-month wise subplot-order of month is not in sequence

Tags: java, r, ggplot2, tableau-api, python-ggplot

enter link description hereHere is my code:

```
data<-read.csv("D:/wggplot.csv", header=TRUE)

ggplot (mydata, aes(x = Temp, y = growh, color = Month)) + geom_hex() +
  facet_wrap(~Month) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")  + theme_gray(20) + labs(y = "growth")
```

This puts the months in alphabetical order in the plot. How can I change my code to get the months in chronological order?

Comment: can you print out this: dput(head(data))

Comment: this was a very simple 1 for any R expert i have put all my code but still...please suggest me guys i need it